# Need help rewriting a bool as a ternary operator

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write more ternary operators for if statements to practice, and I'm getting stuck on turning this into a ternary operator and need a bit of help.

I'm trying to animate the fade in and out of my status, navigation bar, toolbar, and a textslider.

I have:

```
var isHidden = false

@objc func textViewTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {  
    navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(!isHidden, animated: false)
    isHidden = navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.toolbar.isHidden = self.toolbar.isHidden ? false : true
        self.textSlider.isHidden = self.textSlider.isHidden ? false : true
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see, I got the toolbar and textSlider to work as a ternary operator. I need help converting this bit:

```
navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(!isHidden, animated: false)
    isHidden = navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden
```

This is getting into views I can't see and I'm getting twisted up trying to convert it.

Comment: I appreciate you want to practice using the ternary operator, but ultimately you should strive for readability, are you sure using the ternary operator is more readable then what you currently have?

Comment: @TommyBs that's valid. Admittedly, all ternary operators are not that readable to me at my beginner stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use ternary operators here, just writing this would be enough:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.toolbar.isHidden = !self.toolbar.isHidden
    self.textSlider.isHidden = !self.textSlider.isHidden
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}, completion: nil)
```

But I guess you are doing this to practice using the ternary operator, but please be aware that there are cases where the ternary operator is not useful at all. Not every if statement can be converted to one. e.g. this one:

```
if someCondition {
    someAction1()
    someAction2()
} else {
    someActon3()
    someAction4()
}
```

You can't write two statements as one of the operands of the ternary operator.

For the two lines in question, you can just follow the same logic you did with the above lines:

```
navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(isHidden ? false : true, animated: false)
isHidden = isHidden ? false : true // this is really redundant...
```

A more appropriate use case of the ternary operator is when you want to use different values of a non-`Bool` type depending on a condition. For example:

```
label.text = isHidden ? "I am hidden!" : "I am visible!"
```

Comment: You could declare the `isHidden` with a getter which gets the navigation hidden status. Would be easier i guess?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri That could be what the OP meant, but I have too little information so `isHidden` might not be solely linked to navigation bar being hidden.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you. The isHidden was throwing me off. Thank you also for explaining the appropriate use. I've just begun using them and in my excitement that they shrunk my lines of code all over my app, I guess I got a bit overzealous.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10 provides the Bool [.toggle()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/2994863-toggle) function. Or you can roll your own for earlier versions:

```
extension Bool {

    mutating func toggle() {
        self = !self
    }

}
```

Just makes changing Bool values slightly more intuitive.